# Why is there a comma in "'I'd like to be as rich as Marco,' he thought"?

Tags: commas, literature, direct-speech

This is a sentence from a story I was reading:

> 'I'd like to be as rich as Marco,' he thought.

Why is a comma used after the word 'Marco'? Can you please explain the grammar behind that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 'I'd like to be as rich as Marco,' he thought.

Here is a guide on using commas in direct speech.

https://www.lexico.com/grammar/comma#grammar/comma#commas_in_direct_speech

> You also need to use a comma at the end of a piece of direct speech, if the speech comes before the information about who is speaking. In this case, the comma goes inside the quotation mark:

> If the piece of direct speech comes after the information about who is speaking, you need to use a comma to introduce the direct speech. The comma comes before the first quotation mark.

> He thought, 'I'd like to be as rich as Marco.'